# Change permissions (2008 R2) - Do I need to reboot server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, user-permissions

I had to change permissions on a user account in Windows 2008 Server R2. 
Do I need to reboot the server for these new permissions to be recognized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, permissions apply as soon as you change them.

Comment: thanks - - had a bigger problem that I was trying this change for but that's a big help.